# Phantomjs WaitFor with Promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, phantomjs

When `phantom` is used as `node` module, the function [WaitFor](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/master/examples/waitfor.js) that waits for a DOM element condition to be verified  does not work when `page.evaluate` is a `Promise` like:

```
sitepage.evaluate(function() {
  return document.querySelectorAll('.content > ul');
}).then(function(html) {
  sitepage.close();
  phInstance.exit();
  if (done) done(pageContent);
});
```

so this will not work:

```
waitFor(function() {
    return sitepage.evaluate(function() {
      return document.querySelectorAll('.content > ul');
    }).then(function(html) {
      sitepage.close();
      phInstance.exit();
      if (done) done(pageContent);
    });
  },
  function() {
    sitepage.close();
    phInstance.exit();
  }, 1000);
```

In this case the `then` holds the results from the `evaluate` condition. So it possible to implement in the `waitFor` support for the `Promise`?